# How can you set a DIV to use 100% of the remaining space in its parent container?

Tags: html, css

The trouble I'm having is I have the following structured code. Essentially I would like the UL to take up the top 37 pixels of the page, and the div that follows it to take up the *remaining* area of the browser's window.

So if I resize the window, and make it taller, the purple background of the div should fill the entire bottom area. The problem I'm having is that if I set height to 100% on the purple DIV, it creates a scroll bar because its creating the DIV to 100% of the size of the parent, not 100% of the *remaining* area after the UL has been accounted for.

```
<body style="padding:0; margin:0;border-width:1px;border-color:Gray; border-style:dashed; position:absolute; left:0px; right:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px;">
<div style="margin:0; padding:0; left:0px; right:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px;margin:0;height: 100%;border-width:1px;border-color:Green; border-style:dashed;">
    <div style="margin:0; padding:0; height:100%;border-width:1px;border-color:Red; border-style:dashed;">
        <ul style="padding:0;margin:0;border-width:1px;border-color:Blue; border-style:solid; left:0px; right:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px;">
            <li >Test Item</li>
        </ul>

        <div style="height:100%;background-color:Purple;">Test Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I should note that I'm doing my testing in the latest version of Chrome, but I see the same behavior in IE9 and the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: set the overflow: auto on the parent div for starters.   you can also set border: 1px solid red (or any color) on each div as a trouble shooting tool.

Comment: That's the default behavior of a division... Why are you using `position: absolute` on the `<body>` element? Did you mean to use `min-height: 100%`?

Comment: I don't know, even if I take it out and use min-height, the purple does not extend to the full remaining height of the window. And Brian's suggestion didn't change anything either.

Comment: Setting overflow:hidden on the body and height:100% on the body *and* the <HTML> tag seemed to "fix" it. But is that the *right* way and will it break later?

Comment: Which downward versions of IE do you have to serve?

Comment: I recommend to use CSS with classes not inline styles

Comment: THe inline styles are for testing only. It should otherwise make no different. I'd like to see a fix for any browser, so far nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap them using a div. Example

```
<div id="wrapper" style="height: 100%;position:relative;">
<ul>
    <li >Test Item</li>
</ul>

<div style="height:100%;position: absolute; left:0; top:0;padding-top: 39px; z-index: -1">Test Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because there is still a scroll bar for no (apparent) reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with absolut positioning

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/zXV7V/​

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="top">Top</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

---

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap .top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 37px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
.wrap .content {
    position: absolute;
    top:37px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
​
```

Comment: I tried replacing the first div with a UL and it doesn't work.